# How to stop images from disappearing when mouse is moved abruptly over them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In  the code, the icons are images which when you move your mouse swiftly over some tend to disappear.This is mainly happening because i've included transition to reduce the brightness of the image on hover. But when mouse is moved swiftly through images, they disappear for a sec and come back. How to remove this error?

```css
header{
     background: #000;
     color:#FFF;
     text-align:center;
     padding:30px; 
     font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
     font-size:25px;
    }

#iconwrap{float:left;}

    #icon{
    -webkit-transition: 0s -webkit-filter;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .6s; 
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175,0.885,0.320,1.275);
    
    -moz-transition: 0s -webkit-filter;
    -moz-transition-duration: .6s; 
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175,0.885,0.320,1.275);

    -o-transition: 0s -webkit-filter;
    -o-transition-duration: .6s; 
    -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175,0.885,0.320,1.275);
    }
    #icon:hover{ 
    -webkit-filter: brightness(25%);
    -moz-filter: brightness(25%);
    -o-filter: brightness(25%);}
```

```html
<header>
    Project-Mate

<nav>

    <div id="iconwrap">
        <img id="icon" src="http://www.easyicon.net/api/resize_png_new.php?id=548873&size=48" />
     <img id="icon" src="http://www.easyicon.net/api/resize_png_new.php?id=548873&size=48" />
     <img id="icon" src="http://www.easyicon.net/api/resize_png_new.php?id=548873&size=48" />
     <img id="icon" src="http://www.easyicon.net/api/resize_png_new.php?id=548873&size=48" />
     <img id="icon" src="http://www.easyicon.net/api/resize_png_new.php?id=548873&size=48" />
    </div>

</nav>   
<header>
```

Comment: All images seem to be fine for me, not one has disappeared.

Comment: @NewToJS move your mouse swiftly in horizontal direction ...one will definitely disappear for a sec and come back.

Comment: Ah yeah, that takes some mouse movement! :p

Comment: @NewToJS Yep, that's the error!

Comment: No clue what you're talking about, they all seem to work fine for me.

Comment: Nevermind, I see.  You're only using `-webkit-`, and I'm on FireFox.  So it doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: @JamenMarz Good call, i'm using chrome so i didn't spot that. Aishwarya, this doesn't fix your problem but it would be a good idea to update your demo with `-moz-` and `-o-`  for those using FireFox & Opera

Comment: Yup, i'll edit for other browsers!

Comment: use a short delay to cut down flicker. ex: #icon { transition: 600ms 50ms opacity;}

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [tutorial](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-cubic-bezier/), the cubic-bezier function only takes values from 0 to 1 in it's four point parameters. When I changed the value of the fourth point to "1" instead of "1.275" the fade-out problem was solved. Hope it answers your question!

Comment: In this case I guess it would require some timing tweaks. Or it could be an browser implementation bug.